# Are the added dependencies really been compiled by shadow-cljs? If so, why do the values stay the same?

Tags: file, compilation, clojurescript, shadow-cljs

I am following shadow-cljs *Quick Start* documentation on a minimal example of a project. Here is [the link](https://github.com/thheller/shadow-cljs#quick-start).

Initially, I had this `shadow-cljs.edn` file:

```clj
;; shadow-cljs configuration
{:source-paths
 ["src/dev"
  "src/main"
  "src/test"]

 :dev-http {8080 "public"}
 :dependencies
 []

 :builds
 {:frontend
  {:target :browser
   :modules {:main {:init-fn acme.frontend.app/init}}
   }}}
```

In `/Users/pedro/projects/acme-app/src/main/acme/frontend/app.cljs`, I also have:

```
(ns acme.frontend.app)

(defn init []
  (println "Hello World"))
```

I can build and watch it with the command:

```bash
$ npx shadow-cljs compile frontend

shadow-cljs - config: /Users/pedro/projects/acme-app/shadow-cljs.edn
shadow-cljs - updating dependencies
shadow-cljs - dependencies updated
[:frontend] Compiling ...
[:frontend] Build completed. (79 files, 0 compiled, 0 warnings, 4.88s)
```

I have been adding dependencies such as:

```clj
:dependencies [[day8.re-frame/re-frame-10x "1.2.1"]
                [proto-repl "0.3.1"]
                [re-frame "1.2.0"]
                [com.degel/re-frame-firebase "0.9.6-SNAPSHOT"]
                [bidi "2.1.5"]
                [re-com "2.13.2-106-180ea1f-SNAPSHOT-TALLYFOR"]
                [com.andrewmcveigh/cljs-time "0.5.2"]
                [com.pupeno/free-form "0.6.0"]
                [binaryage/dirac "RELEASE"]
                [hickory "0.7.1"]
                [cljs-hash "0.0.2"]
                [medley "1.2.0"]]
```

But, the build does not change in terms of `files`, `compiled`, and `warnings`. Just the time changes a bit - time is probably somewhat random/stochastic `(79 files, 0 compiled, 0 warnings, 5.59s)`.

Are the dependencies **really** been compiled? How do I know if the dependencies were compiled too?

If they are being compiled, why does the number of files stay the same?

Obs.: note that I am not invoking the function being used inside the dependencies - and I do not want to invoke them for debugging reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the `:dependencies` does very little, they'll not be compiled on their own. They are only made available on [the classpath](https://code.thheller.com/blog/shadow-cljs/2021/05/13/paths-paths-paths.html).

They will only be compiled and loaded once you add them the `:require` in the `ns` forms of your files, or dynamically `require` at the REPL. Without an explicit request (ie. `:require`) to load them, they are just passive resources that are unused.